# Retrieve word from chapter

Tags: python

I have a list of about 200,000 words each with about 10 numerical features. The 200,000 words are split into size 500 chunks by some header (eg, "Chapter x"). I want to write a script that does nothing except prompts the user to input a string and then finds that string among the 200,000 words (the word may be in multiple chunks, but in each chunk it will only be found once) and returns the names of the chapter under which the string falls sorted by the value of that word's numerical feature within each chapters. Eg, suppose that the word "twelve" appears in 3 chapters and I want to sort it by feature 1, which has the value 50, 30, 2 in chapters 10, 14, and 9 respectively. I want the o/p:

```
Chapter 10, 50
Chapter 14, 30
Chapter 9, 2
```

Before I even start writing a script, I want to make sure that this is a reasonable task for Python. In other words, will the execution time be in seconds, in minutes? If I instead had 500,000 words, would it still be feasible? I don't want to keep the user waiting.

Comment: Seems reasonable. I think if you do it right it should be in the order of less than a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ballpark time:

Let's say all your words are 10 8-bit string characters (so, 80 bits each), and you need to compare your input string to all 200,000 of them.  That's about 16 million bit-comparison operations.  If your processor is running the code at 1 GHz, you will finish in 0.016 seconds.

Even if I've underestimated the number of operations this task will take by a factor of 100, it will only take about 1 second to execute.